# Add multiple filters in Spree Commerce Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

We need to implement custom filters for categories in spree ecommerce in latest version as seen here https://github.com/spree/spree .

We need to do it in a dynamic way because we have about 100 filters or more to make. The ideal solution would be to show all available filters in admin area and admin can activate/deactivate them for each category.

Current Scenario:
We know how to make a new filter and apply it. But it takes about four methods per filter as shown in the product_filter.rb file linked below.

Some links we have found useful:

https://gist.github.com/maxivak/cc73b88699c9c6b45a95
https://github.com/radar/spree-core/blob/master/lib/spree/product_filters.rb

Comment: I have solved this issue by myself. Now i am creating dynamic filters by meta-programming. Create filters at runtime.

Comment: any hint how you achieved that/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that allows you to filter by multiple properties. It is not ideal (no proper validation etc) but I guess it is better than doing multiple "in" subqueries.

```
        def add_search_scopes(base_scope)
            joins = nil
            conditions = nil
            product_property_alias = nil
            i = 1
            search.each do |name, scope_attribute|
                scope_name = name.to_sym
                # If method is defined in product_filters
                if base_scope.respond_to?(:search_scopes) && base_scope.search_scopes.include?(scope_name.to_sym)
                    base_scope = base_scope.send(scope_name, *scope_attribute)
                else
                    next if scope_attribute.first.empty?
                    # Find property by name
                    property_name = name.gsub('_any', '').gsub('selective_', '')
                    property = Spree::Property.find_by_name(property_name)
                    next unless property

                    # Table joins
                    joins = product if joins.nil?
                    product_property_alias = product_property.alias("filter_product_property_#{i}")
                    joins = joins.join(product_property_alias).on(product[:id].eq(product_property_alias[:product_id]))
                    i += 1

                    # Conditions
                    condition =  product_property_alias[:property_id].eq(property.id)
                                                                     .and(product_property_alias[:value].eq(scope_attribute))

                    conditions = conditions.nil? ? condition : conditions.and(condition)

                end
            end if search.is_a?(Hash)
            joins ? base_scope.joins(joins.join_sources).where(conditions) : base_scope
        end

        def prepare(params)
            super
            @properties[:product] = Spree::Product.arel_table
            @properties[:product_property] = Spree::ProductProperty.arel_table
        end
```